# How to achieve alternating row styles for a responsive table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I think I need JavaScript to solve this but that's why I need help (I've only edited existing JavaScript - never created them).

I have two striped tables nest side-by-side that when viewed on a mobile device, the table on the right moves below the table on the left to look as one continuous table.

The problem is with the table striping only when viewed on a mobile device if the tbody row counts are an even number, I end up with two consecutive rows in the middle being the same color.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .sizesTableContent {
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
    .hider {
        display: none;
    }
}
.sizesAsterisk {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.hanging {
    text-indent: -0.5em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
.sizesTableContent {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.sizesTwoColumn {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.sizes {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.sizes td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sizes th {
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.sizes th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.sizes tbody tr:hover {
    background: #D2DAE3;
}
.sizes tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ffffcc;
}
.sizes tbody tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
    background: #D2DAE3;
}
```

```html
<table class="sizesAsterisk">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="sizesTwoColumn">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sizesTableContent">
                        <table class="sizes" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <col width="33.3%">
                                <col width="33.3%">
                                    <col width="33.4%">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Size in
                                                    <br/>Inches</th>
                                                <th>Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per Ft</th>
                                                <th>Est. Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per 20' Bar</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <!--First column size data go between the tbody tags-->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1" x 1/4</td>
                                                <td>.620</td>
                                                <td>12.40</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-1/4 x 5/15</td>
                                                <td>.960</td>
                                                <td>19.20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-1/2 x 5/16</td>
                                                <td>1.180</td>
                                                <td>23.60</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="hider" style="border-right: 1px solid #000000" width="14px"></td>
                    <td class="hider" width="14px"></td>
                    <td class="sizesTableContent">
                        <table class="sizes" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <col width="33.3%">
                                <col width="33.3%">
                                    <col width="33.4%">
                                        <thead class="hider">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Size in
                                                    <br/>Inches</th>
                                                <th>Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per Ft</th>
                                                <th>Est. Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per 20' Bar</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <!--Second column size data go between the tbody tags-->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-1/2 x 7/16</td>
                                                <td>1.560</td>
                                                <td>31.20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-3/4 x 7/16<span style="color:red"> *</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>1.910</td>
                                                <td>38.20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2" x 1/2<span style="color:red"> *</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>2.587</td>
                                                <td>51.74</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hanging"><!--Asterisk notes go between the td tags-->
            <span style="color:red">* </span>Also in 10' Lengths.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: wrap both tables in a container element with a class, then you can use more specific css selectors in mobile view.

Comment: Do you know how many rows are going to be in your tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't need JavaScript. Simply use some `:last-child` pseudo-selectors in your media query to change the presentation a little more in mobile view. This essentially switches the even/odd backgrounds of the 2nd table only in mobile view:

```
.sizesTableContent:last-child .sizes tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #fff;
}
.sizesTableContent:last-child .sizes tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #ffffcc;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/h9fz13qu/1/)**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .sizesTableContent {
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }
    .hider {
        display: none;
    }
    .sizesTableContent:last-child .sizes tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #fff;
    }
    .sizesTableContent:last-child .sizes tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #ffffcc;
    }
}
.sizesAsterisk {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.hanging {
    text-indent: -0.5em;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
}
.sizesTableContent {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.sizesTwoColumn {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
.sizes {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.sizes td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sizes th {
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #000000;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.sizes th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.sizes tbody tr:hover {
    background: #D2DAE3;
}
.sizes tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ffffcc;
}
.sizes tbody tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
    background: #D2DAE3;
}
```

```html
<table class="sizesAsterisk">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="sizesTwoColumn">
                <tr>
                    <td class="sizesTableContent">
                        <table class="sizes" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <col width="33.3%">
                                <col width="33.3%">
                                    <col width="33.4%">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Size in
                                                    <br/>Inches</th>
                                                <th>Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per Ft</th>
                                                <th>Est. Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per 20' Bar</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <!--First column size data go between the tbody tags-->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1" x 1/4</td>
                                                <td>.620</td>
                                                <td>12.40</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-1/4 x 5/15</td>
                                                <td>.960</td>
                                                <td>19.20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-1/2 x 5/16</td>
                                                <td>1.180</td>
                                                <td>23.60</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="hider" style="border-right: 1px solid #000000" width="14px"></td>
                    <td class="hider" width="14px"></td>
                    <td class="sizesTableContent">
                        <table class="sizes" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <col width="33.3%">
                                <col width="33.3%">
                                    <col width="33.4%">
                                        <thead class="hider">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Size in
                                                    <br/>Inches</th>
                                                <th>Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per Ft</th>
                                                <th>Est. Lbs.
                                                    <br/>Per 20' Bar</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <!--Second column size data go between the tbody tags-->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-1/2 x 7/16</td>
                                                <td>1.560</td>
                                                <td>31.20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>1-3/4 x 7/16<span style="color:red"> *</span>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>1.910</td>
                                                <td>38.20</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>2" x 1/2<span style="color:red"> *</span>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>2.587</td>
                                                <td>51.74</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hanging">
            <!--Asterisk notes go between the td tags-->
<span style="color:red">* </span>Also in 10' Lengths.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```